# Regex match everything after

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a url for which i want to match a certain pattern

> /events/display/id/featured

where

- match everything after /events/
- display is matched into  key
- id and featured are 1 or more matched into a  key

thus i end up with

```
Array (
 [method] => display
[param] => Array ([0]=>id,[1]=>featured,[2]=>true /* if there was another path */)
)
```

so far i have

```
(?:/events/)/(?P<method>.*?)/(?P<parameter>.*?)([^/].*?)
```

But its not working out as expected.

What's wrong with the syntax?

P.S. no i don't want to use parse_url() or php defined function i need a regex

Comment: You have an extra / after events: It's looking for /events//method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
<pre><?php
$subject = '/events/display/id1/param1/id2/param2/id3/param3';

$pattern = '~/events/(?<method>[^/]+)|\G(?!\A)/(?<id>[^/]+)/(?<param>[^/]+)~';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    if (empty($match['method'])) {
        $keyval[] = array('id'=>$match['id'], 'param'=>$match['param']);
    } else {
        $result['method'] = $match['method'];
    }
}
if (isset($keyval)) $result['param'] = $keyval;
print_r($result);
```

pattern details:

```
~
/events/(?<method>[^/]+)   # "events" followed by the method name 
|                          # OR
\G                         # a contiguous match from the precedent
(?!\A)                     # not at the start of the string
/(?<id>[^/]+)              # id
/(?<param>[^/]+)           # param
~
```

Comment: New communication rules on SO tell that I don't shall do so, but however, I will: +1 nice solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a mix of `preg_match()` and `explode()`?:

```
$str = '/events/display/id/featured';
$pattern = '~/events/(?P<method>.*?)/(?P<parameter>.*)~';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

// explode the params by '/'
$matches['parameter'] = explode('/', $matches['parameter']);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(27) "/events/display/id/featured"
  'method' =>
  string(7) "display"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "display"
  'parameter' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "id"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "featured"
  }
  [2] =>
  string(11) "id/featured"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm basically using `preg_match_all()` to recreate functionality similar to `explode()`. Then I'm remapping the results to a new array. Unfortunately this can't be done with Regex alone.

```
<?php

$url = '/events/display/id/featured/something-else';
if(preg_match('!^/events!',$url)){
    $pattern = '!(?<=/)[^/]+!';
    $m = preg_match_all($pattern,$url,$matches);

    $results = array();

    foreach($matches[0] as $key=>$value){
        if($key==1){
            $results['method']=$value;  
        }   elseif(!empty($key)) {
            $results['param'][]=$value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [method] => display
    [param] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => featured
            [2] => something-else
        )

)
```